# angular binding not working in vs code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code to learn Angular and very simple thing is not working.

The below code is in src/app/app.component.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"> 
 </script>
 <body>

 <div ng-app="">
   <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
   <p ng-bind="name"></p>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And when I run from VS Code terminal using ng serve, 
localhost:4200 from Chrome shows the input box but text being typed never appear in the paragraph.

It would be a great help if I can get some help how to find out more to understand what is wrong, even better if some one can give me how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **`angular.js`** syntax which does not work with angular.

Start from **[`here`](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)**.

However here is an example with angular on **[`Stacblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vuwyug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks...it is misleading when I google 'Angular W3School', first thing appears is AngularJS W3School...    Is it correct that AngularJS is the older version of Angular?  I suppose I better study Angular than AngularJS..?

Comment: yeah if you want to learn anything about angular just use -angularjs with the search on google , you will be getting angular related resources

Comment: http://sajeetharan.blogspot.com/2017/08/google-search-tip-for-angular.html

Comment: First install the @angular/cli in your system, then generate a new project with the CLI. It's an easy way to start learning.